# Apache Kafka Consumer - Analytics Platform - Visualize data

Tags: java, apache-kafka, data-visualization, kafka-consumer-api, druid

I am new to Apache Kafka and also to data analytics.

I am able to consume messages from Apache kafka consumer in Java.

Now I want to take these real time data and display it like a dashboard.

I want to visualize all these data using any open source tool.

One tool which I found is Druid but the documentation provided is not enough to learn and proceed with that.

Also I read that Druid is very difficult to install and deploy in production.

Any other tools available to do this? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: imply.io offers "Pivot" of which primary target is Druid.  It's a nice data exploration and visualization tool

Answer (score 1):

you can use Apache Zeppelin https://zeppelin.apache.org/ to visualise your kafka topics. It has a web interface for notebook and it supports java. You can write your code on it and visualise its output

Answer (score 1):

I recently started using Metatron Discovery. https://metatron.app/

It is a free and open source software for data visualization.
It supports kafka, so you can visualize your real-time data with a wide variety of charts.

If you are interested in open source, this will be helpful.
https://github.com/metatron-app/metatron-discovery/

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the Elastic stack. If you get your data with Kafka, then store it in Elasticsearch, you could quickly have a dashboard with Kibana. When I had to install and deploy it, I found it very easy to use.

Comment: As an extension to this, I have started using streamsets (https://streamsets.com/) for connecting Kafka to Elasticsearch. This tool is an open source one and has lot of advantages. Easy UI and interface to play around. Whoever is looking around like me, they can make use of this one.